# Only display data from SQLdatabase if it does not meet contain a certain user in JSP file

Tags: jsp

I have a SQL database and I am displaying the data in a JSP page.

I only want the data to be shown if the user role is not 'admin'

so far I have

```
<c:if test="${user.role != Admin}">
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers.rows}">

                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.secondName}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.handicap}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.cdh}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.societyHcpReduction}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
```

I am not getting any errors but it is still displaying the user who has the Admin role.

Can anyone advise where in my if statement I am going wrong? Or elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the string literal `Admin` and using the `ne` operator instead of `!=`
i.e. `<c:if test="${user.role ne 'Admin'}">`

Comment: If that doesn't help, let us know which version of JSTL you're using.